# Errno 10060 when trying to connect from a local client to the my server using my external ip adress

Tags: python, sockets, server

I am tring to create a multi connection server in python using sockets. Not by any real protocol but by own defined protocol.

I have got my server running correctly with my local ip (127.0.0.1) and now i want my friends to connect but we keep getting this error :[Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I have opened ports correctly and set my server ip to the ip given by ipconfig. Am i missing somthing or doing doing anything wrong?

this is the relevant server code:

```
def initialize():

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # Setup a server socket

    server_port = raw_input("Enter the port to run the server on\n")  # Ask the admin for port
    while server_port.isdigit() is not True:
        server_port = raw_input("Enter the port to run the server on\n")

    server_socket.bind((LOCAL_IP, int(server_port)))  # Bind the server socket to this computer

    inputs.append(server_socket)

    terminated = False
    while not terminated:

        readable_sockets, writable_sockets, error_sockets = select.select(inputs, outputs, [])  # check which of the
        handle_inputs(readable_sockets, server_socket)
        handle_messages(writable_sockets) # this works on my local ip server
        # sockets we expect to use are actually free


def handle_inputs(readable_sockets, server_socket):
    """
    This functions purpose is to read all inputs given by users, and create new requests accordingly

    :param readable_sockets: a list of sockets which are waiting to be read
    :param server_socket: the socket of the server
    """

    for cur_socket in readable_sockets:

        if cur_socket is server_socket:
            new_socket, new_ip = server_socket.accept(1)

            answers_queue.append(Answer(new_socket, Answer.HND_TYPE, 9, "handshake"))
            if new_socket not in outputs:
                outputs.append(new_socket)
```

this is the relvent client code:

```
def main():
    my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    my_socket.connect((EXTERNAL_IP, PORT))
    data = my_socket.recv(1)
    if data == 'H':
        print my_socket.recv(int(my_socket.recv(2)))
    else:
        print "ERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR"
```

Comment: what's `LOCAL_IP`?

Comment: Your code is broken: `recv` reads up to the given number of bytes, not exactly this number.

Comment: @Daniel, the recv uses the protocol i have made up, that why it is a hard coded number. it does work with a local connection

Comment: 10060 is a timeout error, not a connection error. The client code is expecting the server to send a message as soon as the client connects. Where is the server code that actually sends that message? Why are you queuing the message before adding `new_socket` to `outputs`? Is it possible that the server tries to send the queued message prematurely, or worse ignore it?

Comment: @RemyLebeau this is highly unlikely since the server run correctly on local connections

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.1` is a loopback IP, it does not exist outside of the local machine.  If you bind your server socket to `127.0.0.1`, then only clients on the same machine can connect to `127.0.0.1`.

If the server machine is connected to a LAN, and you want clients on the same LAN to connect to your server socket, it must be bound to the server machine's local LAN IP, or to `0.0.0.0` to bind to all available local IPs.

If you want clients from the Internet to connect to your server socket, they must connect to your Internet connection's public IP.

If your server machine is *directly* connected to the Internet modem, then the server machine's LAN IP is the modem's Internet IP.  That is the IP you need to bind your server socket to.  But, if your server machine is behind a LAN router, then you must configure the router to port-forward inbound connections from the router's public IP to the server machine's LAN IP, and then bind your server socket to that LAN IP.

And, of course, if your server machine has a firewall, make sure the desired port is open on it.

That being said, 10060 is a timeout error, not a connection error. The client code you have shown is expecting the server to send a message as soon as the client connects.  But is the server actually sending that message?  You showed code that queues the message, but you did not show the code that actually sends it.

Comment: That is very strange, I have done exactly what you said (i am going from an internet client to a server behind LAN). But that still not working. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Define "not working" exactly. There are many things that can go wrong. Is the client connecting at all, yes or no? If Yes, is the client receiving any data at all, yes or no? Where EXACTLY is the error being reported? At which step in your code? Please be more specific about WHAT exactly is not working.

Comment: I suggest you use a packet sniffer, like Wireshark, to make sure the client connections are reaching the server machine. If you don't see them in the sniffer, then the router is not configured correctly. If you do see them in the sniffer, but your server code is not seeing them, then your server code is faulty.